# Two Sections on Woocommerce Catergory Page

Tags: categories, customization, loop, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to be able to customise the layout of the category pages of my website.

If possible, I would like to make it so that products will appear in two sections, determined by a custom attribute (in this case an attribute we'll call 'Showroom').

This would be a checkbox attribute.

Then on the category page, all the products with the Showroom checkbox ticked will display first under a "From the Showroom header", then all the other non ticked products will displayed under a second heading "From the Storeroom"

Link to website here (http://onthesquareauctions.com/index.php/product-category/emporium/furniture/)

I have included a rough image of what i mean.

[image: Example]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have copy the archive-product.php in your template folder in the woocomerce folder.

Then you edit the file and basically run a loop trough the catgeories you want (for example you category id's are 12 and 24);

```
$product_categories = array(12,24); 
foreach($product_categories as $category){
            $product_options = array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                        'terms'    => (int)$category,
                    ),
                ),
            );

            $product_query = new WP_Query($product_options);    //get all products for this category
//OUTPUT YOUR PRODUCTS HERE 
}//end foreach
```

Then you have all the products for one category in your $product_query query. adjust your output within the foreach loop and you are all set.

Comment: Hey, do you think this would be possible to do with Meta Values instead of Categories?

Need the sorting to be dependant on a custom attribute that the product has instead of what category its in.

Comment: remove the tax_query and add a meta query, as long as it is a custom field it should work.